# How to check if two lists have the same objects in the same order?

Tags: python, list, unit-testing

I have two lists and need to check if they contain the same objects in the same order.

```
list1 = [object1 , object2 , object3]
list2 = [object1 , object2 , object3]
list3 = [object2 , object3 , object1]
```

Comparing list `list1` and `list2`, result should be `true`.

Comparing list `list1` and `list3`, result should be `false`.

Edit: sample list example:`list =   [[<object1 at 0x04130AB0>], [<object2 at 0x04130210>, <object3 at 0x04130A10>]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, Just use `==` to comapare two lists. This should return `True` if two lists having same elements and should be placed in the same order else it returns `False`

```
list1 == list2
```

A function which implements the above logic should look like,

```
def check_lists(list1, list2):
    return list1 == list2
```

Ex:

```
>>> ['object1' , 'object2' , 'object3'] == ['object1' , 'object2' , 'object3']
True
>>> ['object1' , 'object2' , 'object3'] == ['object3', 'object1' , 'object2' ]
False
>>> [['object1' , 'object2'] , ['object3']] == [['object1' , 'object2'] ,['object3']]
True
>>> [['object1' , 'object2'] , ['object3']] == [['object1' , 'object2'] , 'object3']
False
```

Comment: it's an object not string... i'll have references something like list = [[<object1 at 0x04130AB0>], [<object2 at 0x04130210>, <object3 at 0x04130A10>]]

Comment: @FryMan what ever the datatype is, it should work. IS this a list of lists?

Comment: Are you sure this is what the OP wants? They specified "the same objects," with an example of objects at memory locations. From that, it sounds to me like they're looking for identity, not equality. `list1 == list2` checks corresponding elements for equality, not identity.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I think you mixed it up. The == checks for equality, not identity. Two variables are equal if they point to the same place in memory.

Comment: @ubadub - No, I didn't mix anything up. If two references point to the same memory location, the objects they point to will be equal (most probably, for reasonably-defined objects), but the reverse is not necessarily the case, which is my point here. `object1` and `object2` could be different objects that just happen to be equal at that moment.

Comment: @ubadub.  Incorrect.  o1 **is** o2  is the memory test.

Answer (score 2):

A basic `==` will only check if each element in one `list` is equal to the corresponding element in the other `list`. However, given your example of `lst = [[<object1 at 0x04130AB0>], [<object2 at 0x04130210>, <object3 at 0x04130A10>]]`, you are trying to check for identity. Two objects with different identities may compare as "equal," depending on that class's definition of that. Here are some examples where `==` would tell you that two `list`s contain the same objects in the same order when they do not:

```
>>> import collections
>>> a = collections.Counter()
>>> b = collections.Counter()
>>> a is b
False
>>> l1 = [a, b]
>>> l2 = [b, a]
>>> l1 == l2
True
>>> class Person:
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return True
...
>>> a = Person()
>>> b = Person()
>>> a is b
False
>>> l1 = [a, b]
>>> l2 = [b, a]
>>> l1 == l2
True
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a is b
False
>>> l1 = [a, b]
>>> l2 = [b, a]
>>> l1 == l2
True
>>> a.append(0)
>>> l1 == l2
False
```

If you want to check that corresponding elements are actually the same object (identity, not equality), you will need to manually compare identities in some way, such as the following:

```
>>> import collections
>>> a = collections.Counter()
>>> b = collections.Counter()
>>> a is b
False
>>> l1 = [a, b]
>>> l2 = [b, a]
>>> all(x is y for x,y in zip(l1, l2))
False
>>> a = Person()
>>> b = Person()
>>> a is b
False
>>> l1 = [a, b]
>>> l2 = [b, a]
>>> all(x is y for x,y in zip(l1, l2))
False
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a is b
False
>>> l1 = [a, b]
>>> l2 = [b, a]
>>> all(x is y for x,y in zip(l1, l2))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming T's identity over equality distinction matters.

```
def check_id(li1, li2):
    return [id(o) for o in li1] == [id(o) for o in li2]
```